# For planning purposes I am trying to figure out my plumbing under the slab. Can I safely assume that this is the right setup?

Tags: plumbing

I am trying to guess if it is possible to relocate the blue pipe to the right of the vertical one
This is the basement, concrete slab. I can't quite figure out the plumbing for the main drain and I am not sure if I will break the concrete above it.
It is essential for me before starting the work, to know that what I want is possible and there is enough room to install the horizontal blue pipe above the horizontal grey drain

[image]

I am tying to move the yellow pipe in the picture below in the position where the vertical red pipe is
The red pipe is what I am planning to install, the yellow is what I am planning to remove
[image]

Suggestion by ecnerwal
[image]

Here are the real distances for the existing pipes in the basement
16" for the fist to the left vertical black line in the picture (the sink I am relocation and whose pipes are discussed here as a possible replacement for the lower section of the yellow pipe)
4' for the second one.
I also highlighted the contour of what appears to be where the opened  the floor to install these
to the left you can see the clean outs of the soil stack and the dry vent (1.5") this is the yellow pipe I am trying to relocate
[image]

And here is the updated Sketchup model including Ecnerwal's changes
The bath tub will rotate 90 degrees counter clock wise and will be replaced by a shower pan
The sink will move to the south of the picture in the corner where the bath tub ends
[image]

Comment: Missing a picture with red and yellow pipes? You might get a little bit of insight with one of those "drain cameras" (I think you can rent them? Or hire an operator with one for an hour or so.) But it may not be easy to really get a sense of the layout even then.

Comment: I don't see any yellow or red pipes... and you shouldn't assume anything under the slab unless you get it all traced out.

Comment: sorry I just added the picture
let me put it this way ..I am not worried about where the main drain is
I am worried about the way the WC and the drain from shower and sike and the vent are stacked there/ 
The picture is a representation of my wishful thinking. If so will that comply with the code?

Comment: If pipes are iron, a metal detector might read through the slab.

Comment: Having to repair plumbing under a slab I found the best way to locate the pipe mid slab is to have a person tap on the pipe with a hammer while you use a dowel on the slab to your ear move around to the loudest point you can track the pipes very accurately using this method sometimes how they were run was for cheap others for access.

Comment: @wayfaring stranger most slabs have metal wire Mesh or rebar So a metal detector won’t do well even if metal.

Comment: I know there is pipe metal detectors but this is not about it. I am trying to guess what is there and the above is my guess.The question is: will this work? Are the componets correctly positioned

Comment: do you really need to remove the yellow pipe?

Comment: Yes see my previous posts around here, it is part of a separation wall between toilet and sink. Ugly partition, sink is moving away from there also.

Comment: Just a thought for the future: Having the tape measure in that last pic is helpful. However, while drawing the lines on the image, using a text tool to digitally "write" the dimensions on would have been very helpful, too. You've got them written in your description, but remember a lot of your audience here are carpenters/plumbers/electricians - they know how to read a blueprint.

Comment: sorry for that, being frugal for now to expedite the design phase. Once I reach a final solution I will post something more like this https://i.imgur.com/IeogOr2.png (a youtube video I came across)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work if your wishful thinking is correct, though you might find it more practical to leave the stack alone and re-route the yellow vent **around** to where the red pipe is, rather than tearing up the stack to put the vent connection on the opposite side. Messing with the bottom of a stack is not trivial.

IF the pipes to the sink are big enough (and probably not if they were not intended for this) you could also route an above-the-slab dry vent from the sink and the sink drain line would wet-vent the rest, but if it's not big enough that won't fly.

Unclear from your comment, but if the place you "need to move" the yellow pipe is the upper floor, you can run it (properly sloped back to the drain) "horizontal" once it is 6" above the flood level of the highest fixture in the floor it serves (the basement.) Not the highest fixture it serves, the highest fixture on the floor it serves. So you could make the move (if the upper floor is the area of concern) without getting into the concrete.

Comment: The horizontal segment for the existing sink in the basement has 1.5" and I could change it but the yellow pipe is 1.5" too.  Just to be clear thw red pipe is not there, it shows the new position I was considering for the yellow pipe. I did not think about removing it and trying to us the existing sink pipe as wet vent. Isnt this pipe too far up to help the toilet with ventibg?

Comment: The existing sink pipe junction with that horizontal pipe  that goes to the tub in less around 1ft away from grey vertical pipe (soil pipe).

Comment: I added the third picture...is this what you are suggesting ? Build the red pipes as dry vent for the new sink (top left corner of the basement floor) and the existing shower and use the old sink piping to wet vent the toilet ?

Comment: Note that all the horizontal runs in your latest picture need to be "6 inches above the flood level of the highest fixture." The venting rules are complex and depend on which code applies to your locale - I'm under IPC with a few local changes. I think you'd be fine wet venting if you have 2" pipe for the wet part,- your current setup appears to be a dry vent at minimum size, so I doubt that wet venting at that same size is allowable, but there are a number of overlapping rules about allowable wet venting for bathroom groups...

Comment: my current setup is in the second picture, that is closer to wet vent than dry vent for the basement, the red pipe segments in the third picture are not there, that is what I would do since I am not sure how well the wet vent would work.
I am not sure if the current design (yellow pipe in place ony) is OK.  I have had no clogs or odors but I never paid attention to the sound the water makes when it goes down the drains in basement. The tub/shower has not P trap! ...I guess that was part of the wet vent plan (took the risk of getting odors but it provided two venting pats for the toilet?

Comment: the basement toilet would have three venting paths (the soil drain itself, the yellow pipe and bad shower design without a P trap which allows the setup to take in air even via the tub overflow

Comment: I added a picture with the real position of the pipes

Comment: I'm curious, has the floor been broken up and if not what leads you to believe there is no P trap under the tub area.